# JAXB - Dynamic Object Creation from XML Document

Tags: jaxb

I have list of XML files for the user to send the request. By runtime only i comes know what type of object JAXB is going to create. For example if user sends the request like

```
<books>
<name>Java</name>
</books>
```

Then i wants create a Book object. If the user sends the request like

```
<Customer>
<id>1</id>
</Customer>
```

Then i wants to create a Customer object . But when i unmarshalling the XML using JAXB i need to specify the object type like

```
Person person= (Person) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Is this anyway to create those objects dynamically?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the explicit cast, with the code below `object` could hold an instance of `Book` or `Person` based on the content of the XML file.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class, Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file) ;
```